# one(c) vs -one(c) in Julia

Tags: python, julia, ddmlib

What is the meaning of -one(c)?

one(c) is a one-dimensional array of c

```
function DDM_cdf( a, v, w,  t0, rt, c )
@assert c == one(c) || c == -one(c)
```

verification

Comment: `-one(c)` is a negation of multiplicative identity of `typeof(c)` is `c` is not a `Type` and if `c` is a `Type` then a negation of multiplicative identity of `c` if it is a `Type`.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is 'c' in your case? We know from this code that c is not an array, otherwise it would be an error here. If c is a 'number', then this is simply checking if 'c' is set to either '1' or '-1' (for the appropriate numerical type).

Comment: `c` could be an array in general, as e.g. `one(rand(2,2))` is a valid operation.